# Why does best_params_ in GridSearchCV ignore the variance?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) of `best_param_` in `GridSearchCV` states:

> `best_params_` : dict
>
> Parameter setting that gave the best results on the hold out data.

From that, I assumed "best results" means best score (highest accuracy / lowest error) and lowest variance over my k-folds.

However, this is not case as we can see in `cv_results_`:

[image: Image of a result table with 4 hyperparameter values having the best rank]

Here `best_param_` returns `k=5` instead of `k=9` where `mean_test_score` and the variance would be optimal.

I know I can implement my own scoring function or my own `best_param` function using the output of `cv_results_`. But what is the rationale behind not taking the variance into account in the first place?

---

I ran in that situation by applying KNN to iris dataset with 70% train split and a 3-fold cross-validation.

---

Edit: Example code:

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn import datasets

X = datasets.load_iris().data
y = datasets.load_iris().target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.7, test_size=0.3, random_state=62)

knn_model = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()

param_grid = [{"n_neighbors" : np.arange(1, 31, 2)}]
grid_search = model_selection.GridSearchCV(knn_model, param_grid, cv=3, return_train_score=False)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())

results = pd.DataFrame(grid_search.cv_results_)

k_opt = grid_search.best_params_.get("n_neighbors")
print("Value returned by best_param_:",k_opt)
results.head(6)
```

It results in a different table than the image above, but the situation is the same: for k=5 `mean_test_score` and `std_test_score` are optimal. However `best_param_` returns k=1.

Comment: Mind posting your code? I once tested GridSearchCV on wisconsin breast cancer dataset and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @GarbageCollector I had to play around with `random_state` a little bit in order to reproduce the problem. It only appears in some situations.

Comment: Create a custom scoring function that combines the mean and std how you want.  You could even include the value of k in the calculation.

Comment: @BertKellerman Thanks for your advice but that was actually not my question. I tried to clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [GridSearchCV source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a95203b249c1cf392f86d001ad999e29b2392739/sklearn/grid_search.py#L538)

```
    # Find the best parameters by comparing on the mean validation score:
    # note that `sorted` is deterministic in the way it breaks ties
    best = sorted(grid_scores, key=lambda x: x.mean_validation_score,
                  reverse=True)[0]
```

It sorts by mean_val score and that's it. sorted() preserves the existing order for ties, so in this case k=1 is best.

I agree with your thoughts and think a PR could be submitted to have better tie breaking logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So there is no special reasion why to ignore the variance in general?

Comment: They probably left it that way to meet the broadest use case and not make those decisions for the user.  For instance, in some cases prediction time will be the most important metric assuming you have a good enough accuracy.  In other cases, training time could be more important.

Answer (score -1):

In Grid Search ,cv_results_ provides std_test_score which is standard deviation of score. From this you can calculate variance error by squaring it